# Tag merge request for plesk

Tags: discussion

Please consider merging all the [plesk](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/plesk) tags into one. I don't think we need a separate tag for every single Plesk version released.

If possible; block future plesk tag creation and point users against the regular "plesk" tag

Answer (score 6):

Completed Merge - Blocking is a huge ball-o-wax...

Comment: Missed one.  I see that [tag:failed] is still not merged into [tag:plesk].